# How to loop two arrays into a multidimensional array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays called `dates` and `price`.
How do I insert the elements dynamically into the array below without hard coding the values like below:

```
  newData =     [['Year', 'Sales'],
                             ['2004',  1000  ],
                             ['2005',  1170 ],
                             ['2006',  660 ],
                             ['2007',  1030 ],
                             ['2008',  1530 ]];
```

I have tried the method below but it is not working:

```
var newData = [];
for(var i = 0; i<dates.length;i++){
             var newData1 = [dates[i],price[i]];
             newData.push(newData1);
          }
```

Comment: do you realize that you've tagged this in `java`

Comment: That looks like JavaScript, not Java; nor do I see anything JSP-related.

Comment: Still nothing to do with JSP here.

Comment: What you've said doesn't work **does** work (other than not having `['Year', 'Sales']` as its first entry), assuming that you have an array of dates in `dates` and an array of prices in `price` and they have the same number of entries. You'll need to add a more complete [MCVE](/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Do something like:

```
var newData = [];

function addMulti(years, sales) {
    //assuming years and sales are arrays
    for (var i in years) {
        var newData1 = [years[i], sales[i]];

        newData.push(newData1);
    }
}
```

Comment: what if years and sales are of different data types ? eg: data type for years is string whereas for sales is double

Comment: It should work just like so. The function should be called as `addMulti(['2015', '2016', '2017'], [100, 200, 300]);` and they will all get pushed into the array correctly.